# Container margin-top & video player css issues

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm editing an existing Wordpress theme (created child theme) and I'm having formatting issues. Both on mobile and desktop versions of the website.

My first issue is that the first post loads under the header-logo container sometimes depending on browser size, I notice this happens a lot in mobile devices. The "PROMO" post goes missing.

I've increased both the margin-top & padding-top properties but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Do I perhaps have to update the positioning of the container div? If so, what would be the appropriate way? Been reading a few articles and trying a lot of css edits but I feel like I'm just going in circles.

Affected site: http://posteshare.com

Mobile view: http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fposteshare.com%2F

[image: Issue 1]

The other problem I'm encountering is that media embedded on posts are floating on top of my "fixed" header instead of the other way around. I've modified the "position" property to absolute but it seems to break the formatting of the whole page? Been at this for a couple of hours and it's driving me nuts. Any new insight is appreciated. I've ran out of ideas to try.

[image: issue 2[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukWk.png)

Comment: Give `#header-container` a `z-index: 999;`

Comment: @Milan It's not resolving the mobile issue though, any ideas? See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8J6rnzn.png

Tried using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the header appear on top of the other comment, there is a `z-index` property, as said in the comments by @Milan. Basically, what you have to do is...

```
#header-container {
    z-index: 999;
}
/*all the other elements on page except body*/ {
    z-index: /*less than 999*/;
}
```

With this, the header should appear **on top of every element on the page**.

Comment: Thank you! That indeed resolved my "video floating over header" issue. Any ideas on the container margin-top not working properly? It's causing the first post of the page to disappear on the home page and videos appearing under the header container.

Comment: If this proved to be beneficial, please mark it correct if anyone else needs to see it in the future.

Comment: It's not resolving the mobile issue though, any ideas? See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/8J6rnzn.png

Tried using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); but that didn't help. @Yash Jain

Answer (score 1):

If your navigation is 110px height, maybe try adding height + about 20px margin offset to the container like so:

```
.container {
    margin-top: 130px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: both` to `.container` on `grid.css` line **3**